# udev rule for usb attach/detach not triggering

Tags: udev

I'm running RHEL6 and I'm trying to write a udev rule that is triggered upon plugging in and removing usb devices. I created a file called `80-usb.rules` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` and I gave it the following contents (so far nothing too specific, just want to test):

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="touch /tmp/test"
```

I saved the file and plugged in a USB drive to test. However, the file `/tmp/test` was not created.

I figure my udev rule should match my USB drive, since I can run `udevadm info` on the USB drive and at least one of the parent devices has the attribute `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"`.

Why might the udev rule not get triggered?

I tried to run `udevadm test --action=add /path/to/device` and it is clear that the `.rules` file that I wrote is being processed and that my rules are being matched. Here are a few relevant lines from the output:

```
parse_file: reading '/etc/udev/rules.d/80-usb.rules' as rules file
udev_rules_apply_to_event: RUN '/bin/touch /tmp/test' /etc/udev/rules.d/80-usb.rules:1
udevadm_test: run: '/bin/touch /tmp/test'
```

But still, `/tmp/test` does not exist. I am so confused. Clearly this rule is being matched and the rules are being applied. So why doesn't the command specified by `RUN` execute?

Comment: Have you restarted udev after adding the `80-usb.rules` file?   `systemctl restart udev.service`

Comment: Have you tried making a script that executes the `touch` command and setting `RUN` to the path to the script?

Comment: The rule might have write permissions to write in `/`, but  if you are not sure about that, at least while experimenting you should touch `/tmp/udevfile`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but none of your suggestions got me closer to a solution, unfortunately. `udev` isn't actually a service on my machine (`udev-post` is, but restarting that won't and doesn't help any). Writing to /tmp/ is a good idea though. I don't know why I wasn't writing there before. Brain fart, I guess.

Comment: @drs Udev monitors the `/etc/udev` directory, you don't need to notify it when you've changed or added a rule file unless you've put a symbolic link there to a file that's outside `/etc/udev`.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. I'm at a total loss here. When I run `udevadm monitor` I can clearly see the add and remove events when I plug/unplug my USB stick. But when I put the udev event attributes found using this method into a udev rule, I cannot get the rule to trigger and the command specified with `RUN+="..."` to run. I've even tried manually triggering with `udevadm trigger`.

Comment: @jayhendren did you ever resolve this issue? I've got a similar configuration on Debian that does work as expected. Happy to compare notes.

Comment: I think I did, but to be honest, it's been a couple years and I don't really remember well. This was just a little toy that I was working on, and I don't have the box around any more.

Answer (score 3):

Your rule must give an absolute path for executable:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/usr/bin/touch /tmp/test"
```

*Edit:*

And if you want to execute a script, you must tell what shell will execute it:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/bin/sh /path/to/your/script"
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's the issue. `touch` resolves to `/bin/touch` according to the posted debug output.  What's your source for "Your rule must give an absolute path for executable"?

Comment: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html "Execute an external program specified as the assigned value. If no absolute path is given, the program is expected to live in `/usr/lib/udev`; otherwise, the absolute path must be specified."

Comment: Ah. The man page you linked to appears to come from systemd, but the question specifically asks about RHEL 6, which does not have systemd.  I checked the man page for udev on RHEL 6, and no dependency on an absolute path to a program is given there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the path and env issue. My script was missing the #!/bin/bash at the beginning of the same ant that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure the following:

- Paths in the `RUN` command should be absolute
- The file has to be executable
- The `PATH` environment is limited within the execution of you command

At first add this script file to `/lib/udev/touch.sh`

```
vim /lib/udev/touch.sh
```

in that file write:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/test
```

make it executable:

```
chmod +x /lib/udev/touch.sh
```

and change your rules file to:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/lib/udev/touch.sh"
```

reload your udev rules

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

This will read your rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d/*` again. Changes will not apply until now.

Note that udev executes your script with a reduced `PATH` environment. You have to ensure that any binary that's not within the configured paths has to be accessed with a full path. You could also extend the `PATH` environment within your script.

Check what path is defined by logging the `set` output to a log file from your wrapper script:

```
set >>/tmp/udev-env-test
```

It might look like this:

```
PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
```

Comment: it just can run the script not a command